Pine Script - buy sell logic
My question is to generate buy signal and sell signal
is_new_day = timeframe.change("D")

bgcolor(is_new_day ? color.new(color.blue, 85) : na)

var int open_idx = na
var int digit_idx = na

if (is_new_day)
    
    open_idx := bar_index

    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(openingPrice), textcolor=color.white)

    int sum_digit = f_get_sum(calculationResult)

    while (sum_digit >= 10)
        sum_digit := f_get_sum(sum_digit)

    digit_idx := sum_digit

1st signal shows properly which means when target candle high is broken it show signal on new 5mins candle open, but when it is reversal signal which is 2nd signal it shows immediately not on new candle open. how to fix it
// Variable to store the line IDs for high and low
var line highLine = na
var line lowLine = na
var float targetHigh = na
var float targetLow = na


// Calculate the time for the target candle from market open (9:15 AM)
marketOpenTime = timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, 09, 15) // Market open time at 9:15 AM
targetCandleTime = marketOpenTime + (digit_idx * 5 * 60 * 1000) // Time of the target candle based on singleDigitSum

// Declare variables to store the conditions for buy and sell signals
var bool buySignal = false
var bool sellSignal = false

// Declare variables to store if signals have been triggered
var bool buyTriggered = false
var bool sellTriggered = false

// Reset buy and sell triggers at the beginning of each new day
if (dayofweek != dayofweek[1])
    buyTriggered := false
    sellTriggered := false

// Plotting logic
if (time[1] < targetCandleTime and time >= targetCandleTime)
    // Get high and low values for that candle
    targetHigh := high[1]
    targetLow := low[1]
    
    // Create or update high line
    if na(highLine)
        highLine := line.new(x1=bar_index[1], y1=targetHigh, x2=bar_index, y2=targetHigh, width=2, color=color.green)
    else
        line.set_xy1(highLine, x=bar_index[1], y=targetHigh)
        line.set_xy2(highLine, x=bar_index, y=targetHigh)
    
    // Create or update low line
    if na(lowLine)
        lowLine := line.new(x1=bar_index[1], y1=targetLow, x2=bar_index, y2=targetLow, width=2, color=color.red)
    else
        line.set_xy1(lowLine, x=bar_index[1], y=targetLow)
        line.set_xy2(lowLine, x=bar_index, y=targetLow)

// Check for buy and sell conditions after the target candle time
if (time > targetCandleTime)
    if (high > targetHigh and not buyTriggered)
        buySignal := true
        buyTriggered := true
    else
        buySignal := false

    if (low < targetLow and not sellTriggered)
        sellSignal := true
        sellTriggered := true
    else
        sellSignal := false

// Plot buy and sell signals using the conditions stored in variables
plotshape(series=buySignal, title="Buy Signal", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, style=shape.triangleup, text="BUY")
plotshape(series=sellSignal, title="Sell Signal", location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, style=shape.triangledown, text="SELL")


1st signal shows properly which means when target candle high is broken it show signal on new 5mins candle open, but when it is reversal signal which is 2nd signal it shows immediately not on new candle open. how to fix it
